# Reliable cube root in Haskell

Tags: haskell, root

I am doing [question 62](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=62) at project euler and came up with the following to test whether a number is cubic:

```
isInt x = x == fromInteger (round x)
isCube x= isInt $ x**(1/3)
```

But due to floating point error, it returns incorrect results:

```
*Main> isCube (384^3)
False
```

Is there a way to implement a more reliable cube test?

On a side-note, here is the rest of my solution, which doesn't work because of a type interface error on `filter (isCube) (perms n)`:

```
cubes = [n^3|n<-[1..]]
perms n = map read $ permutations $ show n :: [Integer]
answer = head [n|n<-cubes,(length $ filter (isCube) (perms n)) == 5]
```

What do I need to do to fix the error?

```
No instances for (Floating Integer, RealFrac Integer)
   arising from a use of `isCube' at prob62.hs:10:44-49
```

Any optimisations are also welcome ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to avoid using floating point numbers as much as possible, especially when you have a problem which concerns integer values. Floating point numbers have problems with rounding and that certain values (like 1/3) cannot be represented exactly. So it's no surprise that you get mysterious answers.

First of all, in order to fix your type error you have to redefine `isCube`. If you check it's type signature it looks like this:

```
isCube :: (RealFrac a, Floating a) => a -> Bool
```

Note that it expects something that is of class `Floating` as its first argument. Your problem is that you want to use this function on integer values and integers are not an instance of `Floating`. You can redefine `isCube` like this to make the function type check.

```
isCube x = isInt $ (fromIntegral x) ** (1/3)
```

However, that will not make your program correct.

One way to make your program more correct is to do what Henrik suggested. It would look like this:

```
isCube x = (round (fromIntegral x ** (1/3))) ^ 3 == x
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Don't know much about Haskell, but I would take the cube root, round to the nearerst integer, take the cube, and compare to the original value.

Answer (score 1):

For another approach useful for `Integer` values have a look at the `integerCubeRoot` function in the [arithmoi package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.0.3/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Powers-Cubes.html).

Example:

```
ghci> import Math.NumberTheory.Powers.Cube
ghci> let x = 12345^3333
ghci> length $ show x
13637
ghci> isCube x
True
ghci> isCube (x+1)
False
ghci> length $ show $ integerCubeRoot x
4546
```

Answer (score 0):

`perms` has the type `[Integer]`. `isCube` has the type `(RealFrac a, Floating a) => a -> Bool` (as you can check in GHCI). The `RealFrac` constraint comes from `round x`, the `Floating` constraint comes from `x**(1/3)`. Since `Integer` is neither `RealFrac` nor `Floating`, `isCube` *can't* be used as `Integer -> Bool`. So `filter isCube (perms n)` doesn't make sense.

So you need to fix `isCube` to work properly on `Integer`s:

```
isCube x = isInt $ (fromInteger x)**(1/3)
```

In fact, the reason `isCube (384^3)` even compiles is that it "really" means `isCube ((fromInteger 384)^(fromInteger 3))`.

Of course, this will still work badly due to floating point errors. Basically, checking floating numbers for equality, as you do in `isInt`, is almost always a bad idea. See other answers for explanation how to make a better test.